# Extend functionality of function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is declared like this:

```
    function Plugin(option) {
       //logic here
    }
    $.fn.validator = Plugin
```

I need to extend this function with some logic so that it does something more like this:

```
    function Plugin(option) {
       if (myvariable == true)
       {
           //seperate logic
           return;
       }
       //logic here
    }
```

The trick is that I need to add that if statement into the function dynamically, the code that has the Plugin function gets updated frequently and I don't want to re-add that logic every time the file changes. As of right now I just create the whole function with all the logic and replace the old one with it. But this seems like a lot of wasted code. I was hoping there was a way to simply merge them, so I tried.

```
    function Plugin(option) {
       //logic here
    }
    function extendedPlugin(option) {
       //seperate logic here
    }
  $.fn.validator = $.extend(Plugin, extendedPlugin);
    //or
  $.fn.extend($.fn.validator, extendedPlugin)
```

I've tried a couple variations of that logic at the bottom but it just returns the first function every time, is there a way to merge them since functions are technically objects aren't they?
I think I may need to do something with prototypes but my understanding of them is still very limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Plugin` is directly written in some third party code, you can rename and replace the old function:

```
var OldPlugin = Plugin;
Plugin = function(option)
{
    if (myvariable == true)
    {
        //seperate logic
        return /* anything? */;
    }
    return OldPlugin.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Of course, any assigned references to `OldPlugin` must be replaced too:

```
$.fn.validator = Plugin; // After redefining "Plugin"
```

If `Plugin` is not directly written anywhere, but only called via `$.fn.validator`, then I would leave the original function intact and simply assign a new function to `$.fn.validator`, from where you can call the original `Plugin` function.

Comment: You should be using `.apply()`, not `.call()`for that particular situation.

Comment: And I think you should `return this;` to keep jq chaining

Comment: @A.Wolff OP provided a `return;` in his code, I just copied that.

Comment: @Siguza ya but if original plugin returns matched set of elements, you should do the same, otherwise `return;` would be more relevant, that's true.

Comment: Yah the return was psuedocode the actual return would make no sense in this context. This worked great though, in my particular scenario I didn't have to save the original to the "OldPlugin" variable, I just added the   Plugin.apply(this, arguments); at the end of extendedPlugin and overwrote validator, but same concept thanks! (will accept soon)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't simply call the old function from the extended one?

```
function Plugin(option) {
   //logic here
}
function extendedPlugin(option) {
   //seperate logic here
   // then call Plugin?
   return Plugin.call(this, option);
}
```

If you need the new function to have the original name, you can instead do what @Siguza answered

Comment: The value of `this` will not be correct when the old one is called this way.

Comment: @jfriend00 Well spotted, I guess apply() is needed to preserve it. Editing.

Comment: `.apply()` accepts an array as the 2nd argument.  If you're going to just pass the argument itself, then you need `.call()`.  And, you have to show how `extendedPlugin` gets hooked into jQuery in the first place.  The answer as it stands is incomplete.

Comment: I corrected the `.call()` - as for attaching to jQuery, isn't it largely irrelevant how it is done? something like `$.fn.pluginName = extendedPlugin` should do the trick?

Comment: I don't know how you can say it's irrelevant.  It's a required part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use JsonNode it will be more easy
try doing this way

```
function plugin(option){
   option.execute();
}

$.fn.validator = Plugin;
```

And implement in this way

```
var process1 = {
       "execute":function(){
           alert('hello proccess #1');
       }
      };
var process2 = {
       "execute":function(){
           alert('hello process #2');
       }
      };

$.fn.validator(process1);
$.fn.validator(process2);
```

Or

```
if(myvariable){
     $.fn.validator(process1);
}else{
    $.fn.validator(process2);
}
```

Comment: This implementation is a pattern design most used in software development. It's make it more open and you can change the behavior dynamically

Comment: You don't have to comment on your own answer, you can just edit it and append the information :)
That said, I don't see how this answers the question about extending a function.